# Avoid naming different asyncio tasks with the same variable to prevent unstoppable tasks

Tags: python, ipython, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a live-coding environment where coders can create and stop asynchronous tasks.

I start up an interactive python session / asyncio REPL with

`python -m asyncio`.

Then I allow users to create asynchronous tasks by name such as the following:

```
import asyncio # executed with 'python -m asyncio' command

# simple async function
async def sleep(sleep_time):
    while True:
        print(f'sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds.')
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)

x = asyncio.create_task(sleep(2))
y = asyncio.create_task(sleep(4))
```

This creates two asynchronously running tasks, x and y.

These tasks can be easily stopped with

`x.cancel()` and `y.cancel()`.

But if the user executes a new task with the same name `x = asyncio.create_task(sleep(3))` before executing `x.cancel()`, both "x" tasks will be running at the same time.  `x.cancel()` will stop the last definition of `x` (sleeping for 3 seconds) but then the original definition of x--sleeping for 2 seconds--will still be running.  There is no easy way to stop this `x` task that is still running in the background.  `x.cancel()` returns `False` instead of `True`.

My goal is to avoid unstoppable tasks running in the background if the user accidentally uses the same variable name twice.  Is there a way to prevent users from assigning a new definition to the `x` variable?  Or a better strategy altogether?

Either asyncio-specific or base Python solutions are acceptable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if "x" in globals():
    x.cancel()
    del x
```

Something like this may work? `if "x" in globals():` checks whether x is defined or not, `del x` "undefines" `x`.

Or maybe use `try`: do a cancel and catch `NameError` exception in case `x` is not defined

```
try:
    x.cancel()
except NameError:
    ...
```

If you just want to `prevent the user from launching a new task with the same name as an existing task`, the same technique may still be used, maybe something along tihs line:

```py
if "x" in globals():
    if not x.done():
       print(" Another task with the same name is running... ")
    else:
       x = asyncio.create_task(sleep(3))
else:
    x = asyncio.create_task(sleep(3))
```

Comment: this is a cool technique but I'm not trying to prevent errors resulting from stopping an undefined process.  i'm trying to prevent the user from launching a new task with the same name as an existing task.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `if 'x' in globals()` still work? See my edited answer.

Comment: not quite but i appreciate it.   i think i need to wrap `asyncio.create_task(sleep(3))` in a function/class that somehow raises an error if the left-hand side of the equals sign (`x`) exists in `globals()`.  not sure if this is possible!